# How to call instance variables in another class's if statement

Tags: java

Here is the question the instructor provided us with:  I am unsure as to how to make an if statement that will check variables I created in the BikeTester class. The variables I am using were declared as instance variables in the Bike Class. Could anyone please help me solve step 4 in the biketester class?

Bike Class

1. Create a class called Bike which has only the following instance variables:

   - Number of wheels
   - Diameter of tires
   - Manufacturer name
   - Year built
2. Create the no-argument constructor
3. Create the constructor which uses all fields as parameters
4. Write the getter and setter methods for all instance variables
5. Override the toString method using the example shown above

There should be NO main method in the Bike class.

BikeTester Class

1. Create a class called BikeTester which constructs 10 different Bike objects
2. Add each Bike object to an array
3. Use a for loop to SOP each Bike reference
4. Use a second for loop to SOP only those bikes that are built after 2004 and have a wheel diameter of greater than 4

I am on the last step (step 4 in part 2).

I have the following code:

// four argument constructor from the Bike Class

> public Bike(int wheels, double tires, String manuf, int year)
>
> ```
> {
>
> numWheels = wheels;
>
> diameterOfTires = tires;
>
> manufacturer = manuf;
>
> yearBuilt = year;
>
> }
> ```

```
Bike bike10 = new Bike(5, 2.5, "Bob", 1995);
```

//excluded the other 9 bike objects to just grasp the idea.

```
Bike[] bikes = new Bike[10]; 

bikes[0] = bike1;
bikes[1] = bike2;
bikes[2] = bike3;
bikes[3] = bike4;
bikes[4] = bike5;
bikes[5] = bike6;
bikes[6] = bike7;
bikes[7] = bike8;
bikes[8] = bike9;
bikes[9] = bike10;
```

//**step 4 that i need help on**

for (int y = 0; y < bikes.length; y++) //my loop to solve the problem (doesnt work)

{

```
  if(yearBuilt > 2004 && diameterOfTires > 4)
```

{

```
   System.out.println(bikes[y]); 
  }
```

}

Thank you! any help would be nice as I am stuck trying to solve this!

Comment: Getters and settters?

Answer (score 0):

The Bike should have a property that allows you to get the year made.

You can use

```
for (Bike b : bikes) {
    if(b.getYearBuilt() > 2004 && b.getTireDiameter() > 4) {
        // whatever you want to do here.
    }
}
```

or if you need to use an indexed for loop, you can use

```
for (int i = 0; i < bikes.length; i++) {
    if(bikes[i].getYearBuilt() > 2004 && bikes[i].getTireDiameter() > 4) {
        // whatever you want to do here.
    }
}
```

Comment: @xtremeslice If this solution solves your problem, you should accept this solution by clicking the tick and this problem will be considered solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what's wrong when you run your code. Doesn't it compile, do you get exceptions, does it print things you don't want or don't you see nothing at all?

However, I can give a general suggestion on how you may solve this. If you have created setters and getters in the Bike class (`int getNumWheels()`, `void setNumWheels(int)` etc.), you can use them to get each bike's instance variables.

```
for (y = 0; y < bikes.length; y++) {
    if (bikes[y].getYearsBuilt() > 2004 && bikes[y].getDiameterOfTires() > 4) {
        System.out.println(bikes[y]);
  }
}
```

This code will loop through your array of bikes (provided that you have it declared in the same class as this code, or else you have to first get it.

For each iteration of the loop, you have to pick a specific bike to test for build year and tire diameter. To do this, you use the loop index `y` to get a Bike object, and then call the relevant getters.

Whenever the `if` statement is true, `System.out.println(bikes[y])` is called to print out the `String toString()` method of the Bike class. In case you haven't overridden that method, you will only see the class name and a hash code (e.g. `java.lang.String@a132d3`).